# NoMethodError when asking for a model's attribute value in Application Mailer (Rails, RSpec, FactoryGirl)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to test a very basic example with `RSpec` and `FactoryGirl`. I have built a `GlobalSetting` model to keep my variables and change them dynamically, so it contains `(:id, :name, :val)` which are obvious.

Unfortunately the simplest example fails as:

```
/app/mailers/application_mailer.rb:3:in `<class:ApplicationMailer>': undefined method `val' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

and I suspect that the FactoryGirl elements aren't persisted to the database before being called by application_mailer.

**application_mailer.rb**

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default_from_email = GlobalSetting.find_by(name: "DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL").val

  default from: default_from_email
  layout 'mailer'

end
```

**application_mailer_spec.rb**

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe ApplicationMailer, type: :mailer do
  let!(:default_from_email) { FactoryGirl.create(:default_from_email)}
  let!(:ol_internal_dl) { FactoryGirl.create(:ol_internal_dl)}

  before(:each) do
    ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test
    ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries = []
  end

  it 'should send an email' do
    pending
  end
end
```

**global_settings.rb** (FactoryGirl)

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: global_settings
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string
#  val        :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :ol_internal_dl do
    name "OL_INTERNAL_DL"
    val "internal@email.com"
  end

  factory :default_from_email do
    name "DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL"
    val "default@email.com"
  end

end
```

How can I "pass the test" ?

Comment: you can try to stub that value instead of creating a record. As well try to debug if that `default_from_email` is persisted and has no errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is your `FactoryGirl` definition.  `FactoryGirl`, by default, uses the name of the factory to "guess" the associated class name.  In your case, you called the factory `:default_from_email` but I am guessing that you don't have a class by that name?

Try adding `class: GlobalSetting` to the factory definition, like this:

```rb
factory :default_from_email, class: GlobalSetting do
    name "DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL"
    val "default@email.com"
end
```

From the [FactoryGirl documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Defining_factories):

```rb
# This will guess the User class
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name "John"
    last_name  "Doe"
    admin false
  end

  # This will use the User class (Admin would have been guessed)
  factory :admin, class: User do
    first_name "Admin"
    last_name  "User"
    admin      true
  end
end
```

Update: Based on your comment, and after looking at your code closely, the problem appears to be that you are setting a local variable in your class, `default_from_email`.  When this class is `require`d in your tests, it tries to call `#find_by` and since you don't have that record in your database, your test(s) fail before anything can even execute.  Some possible solutions:

1. Change your `#find_by` to `find_or_create`
2. Seed your database prior to running your test and `require`-ing your ApplicationMailer, then the record should exist and you will not see that `nil` error.

Comment: No I don't have a class with that name and thanks for pointing out the `class:` part. However, it seems that it doesn't want to work, because I am receiving the same error as before.

Comment: find_or_create would require me to change the code for all environments. Is it safe to change it from _by to _or_create ? Now for the second case, I need to understand what will I have to do.

Comment: A safer alternative that would not force you to change the code would be to seed the database with this value, and *then* run your test(s).  This would make your test environment similar to production, where I assume you would already have this value in your database.